# ggscatter displays a positive pearson correlation coefficient in kaggle notebook instead of a negative (R)

Tags: r, ggplot2, kaggle, ggpubr

I'm currently working on my first kaggle notebook and faced the issue stated in the title. The minus is only missing in kaggle, as you can see in the pictures. As I want to demonstrate a negative correlation, it is important to see the R is **-** 0.6.

[plot in kaggle notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBevL.png) 
[plot in RStudio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8yFAS.png)

Here is the code I use in both pictures:

```
ggscatter(activity_sleep, x = "TotalMinutesAsleep", 
          y = "SedentaryMinutes", shape = 21, add = "loess",
          add.params = list(color = "blue", fill = "darkgrey"),
          conf.int = TRUE, cor.coef = TRUE, cor.method = "pearson") + 
          labs(title="Sedentary Minutes vs. Minutes Asleep")
```

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: A lowess or gam regression curve is not an appropriate way to show monotonous negative correlation. Pearson is global and not local.

Comment: It looks like a font problem:  there's space for a sign, it's just not showing up.  The RStudio display shows a long dash (different from the one used in the p-value).  You haven't told us how to reproduce what you did, so I can't suggest any way to fix it.

Comment: @danlooo Thanks for the advice, will use the reg.line instead. Has the global property anything to do with the sign display error?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a kaggle bug in the graphics driver.  Running this code in kaggle also leaves out the minus sign:

```
plot(1, main = expression(-1))
```

On the other hand, this works:

```
plot(1, main = "-1")
```

According to the docs for `ggpubr::ggscatter()`, you should be able to choose to display the stats in text rather than using an expression, but it didn't work when I tried this:

```
activity_sleep <- tibble::tibble(TotalMinutesAsleep = rnorm(20),
   SedentaryMinutes = rnorm(20) - TotalMinutesAsleep)
ggpubr::ggscatter(activity_sleep, x = "TotalMinutesAsleep", 
                  y = "SedentaryMinutes", shape = 21, add = "loess" ,
                  add.params = list(color = "blue", fill = "darkgrey"), 
                  conf.int = TRUE, 
                  cor.coef = TRUE, cor.method = "pearson", 
                  cor.coef.args = list(output.type = "text")) +
    labs(title="Sedentary Minutes vs. Minutes Asleep")
```

**Edited to add:**  I reported the bug to kaggle and they replied:  "This is a suitable question to best ask in the discussion or competition forums."   So I guess it's not going to be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

@user2554330
Thank you for your help! Based on your input I figured out how to solve the issue following this [doc.](https://rpkgs.datanovia.com/ggpubr/reference/stat_cor.html)

The code now looks like this:

```
ggscatter(activity_sleep, y = "Calories", x = "SedentaryMinutes", 
      shape = 20, 
      add = "reg.line", 
      add.params = list(color = "blue", fill = "darkgrey"), 
      conf.int = TRUE) + 
      stat_cor(
          aes(label = ..r.label..), label.x = 3,
          method = "pearson",
          output.type = "text")
```

If output.type = "expression", kaggle does not show the minus. All other options work.